# wordpress is not working after transferring the website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've transferred the website to new hosting...
well I've changed the `wp-config` as it is necessary afterword...
the website is not coming up... it shows

`Oops! This link appears to be broken`.

```
Suggestions:
Search on Google:
```

well I've tried to change the url prefixes to http://example.com/ form demo.example.net/example but still nothing changes...
when I try to reach wp-admin by typing http://armeniantradenetwork.com/wp-admin it redirects me to link http://demo.softty.net/atn/wp-admin 
plz help meeeeeeeeee!!!

Comment: Have you changed DNS entries for your site?

Comment: Although this is not an answer to your question but if you find yourself migrating wp sites in the future there is a great plugin for this called duplicator  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: yes Maksym Polshcha the DNS is working normally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If domain has change, you need to edit `/wp-content/themes/*theme name*/functions.php` and add this

```
update_option('siteurl','http://armeniantradenetwork.com/');
update_option('home','http://armeniantradenetwork.com/');
```

*Update*
Next login to admin panel, go to *Settings*->*Permalinks* and just click *Save Changes* - it will rebuild all permalinks.

Comment: correct! OR you can edit this 2 values from phpmyadmin, wp_options or *your prefix*_options also :)

Comment: I followed all these steps > but still it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the wp_options table and update the references from the old location to the new one. If you use something like phpMyAdmin, you can do

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_value` LIKE '%demo.softty.net%'
```

You should get at least the options "siteurl" and "home". Update those and it should work again.

Comment: Also check the "themes" table while you're in phpMyAdmin. Also posts may have hard urls for things such as images that will also need changing.

Comment: ahahahahaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....))))
thank yooooooouuuuuuuuuuuu....jprofitt
now Everything is working perfectly...
you are gr8... 
thank you soooo much...)))

Comment: No Images are normall as I have replaced the urls with php code but something went wrong and it didn't replaced in options table...

Answer (score 0):

@miszczu offered a good solution above.

There is another solution also, IF you have access to your phpmyadmin:

**wp_options** OR **yourprefix_options** table -> **siteurl** field & **home** field. Edit them to your current domain name, full domain.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify two things

1. As per miszczu  said: update 'siteurl' and 'home' options in the database.
2. Make sure you have correct .htaccess file or generate new one from wp-admin->Settings->Permalink.

The regular urls (urls similar to ?p=1) should work if there is no htaccess.

Comment: He won't be able to login untill he change `siteurl` and `home`, because it will redirect to old url (which doesnt exist on new domain) but you're right, I forgot about updating permalinks (:

Comment: well thanks...
I've changed the url so trgular ?p=1
but it don't recognize the /%postname%/ urls and recognize only /index.php/%postname%/ how can I change it?

Comment: Rebuild your .htaccess. In wp-admin, go to Settings->Permalinks, select the /%postname% and save the configuration. You may see a warning message if WP is not able to create .htacces. In that case, you have to create it by your own and follow the instructions.